# Add navigation buttons to an AbstractCell

Tags: java, css, gwt

I've created an `AbstractCell<String>` to create the header that says "welcome to your mobile..." and I would like to add two buttons in this `AbstractCell`: the first to return to the previous page, and the second to return to the welcome page.
I've used to create the header element a class that extends `AbstractCell<String>` using this code:

```
public class HeaderCell extends AbstractCell<String> {

    interface Templates extends SafeHtmlTemplates {

        String style = "HeaderPanel";

        @SafeHtmlTemplates.Template("<div class=\""+style+"\">{0}</div>")
        SafeHtml cell(SafeHtml value);
    }

    private Templates templates = GWT.create(Templates.class);

    interface templateWithButton extends SafeHtmlTemplates {

    }
    @Override
    public void render(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context,
            String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
        SafeHtml safeValue = SafeHtmlUtils.fromString(value);

        SafeHtml rendered = templates.cell(safeValue);

        sb.append(rendered);
    }

}
```

Is there any way to add these two buttons?
Please notice the header cell wich is colored in black.
PS: To set the header element looking like the image below, I use this CSS:

```
.HeaderPanel {
    -moz-box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 15px 1px #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 15px 1px #ffffff;
    box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 15px 1px #ffffff;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #242524
        ), color-stop(1, #242524) );
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #242524 5%, #242524 100%);
    background-color: #242524;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 8px 36px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 29px #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[image: http://hpics.li/5e81f65]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure if this is the best implementation, but it works for me.
-- First, add this to your constructor:

```
public HeaderCell() {
   super("click", "keydown");
}
```

-- Then, override the onBrowserEvent:

```
@Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent, String value, NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater) {
      // Let AbstractCell handle the keydown event.
      super.onBrowserEvent(context, parent, value, event, valueUpdater);   
      // Handle the click event.
      if ("click".equals(event.getType())) {
        EventTarget eventTarget = event.getEventTarget();
       // in here we check whether the cell that was being clicked is an image, not the entire cell
        if(eventTarget.toString().contains("img src") && !eventTarget.toString().contains("<div class")){
            // do something if it's indeed the image that was clicked
        }
      }
    }
```

Cheers, Lin

Answer (score 0):

```
// create the button element 
Element button = DOM.createButton(); 

// here you can alter the html based on your needs
button.setInnerHTML(<"button type="button">Click Me! <"/button>");

// add it to the safehtmlbuilder
sb.appendHtmlConstant(button.getInnerHTML());
```

Comment: I notice that the button is added below the HeaderCell. I would that it comes in the same line just like this demo: http://www.ambigtion.com/gwtmobileui/. I'll be greatful if you can help me. Thanks

Comment: Oh in that case, just make a table out of it. Here some example: sb.appendHtmlConstant("<table>");
sb.appendHtmlConstant("<tr>");
sb.appendHtmlConstant("<td>");
sb.appendHtmlConstant("<img src = "some image url" width=20 height=20>"); 
sb.appendHtmlConstant("</td>");
sb.appendHtmlConstant("<td>");
sb.appendHtmlConstant(button.getInnerHTML()); 
sb.appendHtmlConstant("</td>");

Comment: And do you know how to add an action listner for the image tag?
 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What about using CompositeCell with ActionCells for your buttons?

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/CompositeCell.html

```
new CompositeCell<C>(Arrays.<HasCell<C, ?>>asList(
    new IdentityColumn<C>(new ActionCell<C>("<", new Delegate<C>() { ... })),
    new Column<C, String>(new HeaderCell()) { ... },
    new IdentityColumn<C>(new ActionCell<C>(">", new Delegate<C>() { ... }))
));
```

Comment: Would you please explain more? Thanks

Comment: CompositeCell will put each individual Cell next to each other. My code sample should put a button on either side of your header cell (i.e., [<] header [>] ) and if that's what you're looking for you can just copy that code, replace C with your Cell type and implements the ... elements.